# Inserting missing lines and values in EXCEL

Tags: excel

I have the following table:

```
Date               Value    Date Diff   Hours Diff
29/12/2014 8:00     24.940      
29/12/2014 9:00     24.960  0.04          1
29/12/2014 11:00    25.020  0.08          2
29/12/2014 12:00    25.070  0.05          1
```

The column `Date DifF` is calculated by subtracting the values of lines in the `Date` column (`=A2-A1`). The `Hours Diff` is calculated by multiplying the `Date DifF` by 24 (`=C2*24`).
In case the values of `Hours Diff` is greater than 1 I would like to insert at the right line additional hours so there will be one line per hour.
For instance, the third line was added with the missing value of `Date` (29/12/2014 10:00):

```
Date                   Value      Date Diff Hours Diff
    29/12/2014 8:00     24.940      
    29/12/2014 9:00     24.960  0.04          1
    29/12/2014 10:00                          1
    29/12/2014 11:00    25.020  0.08          1
    29/12/2014 12:00    25.070  0.05          1
```

Afterwards, I would like to fill in and correct the values of the columns: `Value` and `Date Diff`. The `Value` is equal to the delta of Values divided by the number of new lines + 1 (`B4-B2/2`) `(25.020 - 24.960)/2` which is equal to 
`0.03`.
The new table will be:

```
Date                   Value      Date Diff Hours Diff
    29/12/2014 8:00     24.940      
    29/12/2014 9:00     24.960  0.04          1
    29/12/2014 10:00    24.990  0.03          1
    29/12/2014 11:00    25.020  0.03          1
    29/12/2014 12:00    25.070  0.05          1
```

Comment: What are you using to insert this data into Excel?  Is this an export from SQL Server?  VBScript?  PowerShell?  I don't think you are telling us the whole story here..  I could be wrong, but the way I am reading this is you have a data extract from some system and you want it into Excel.

Comment: Thanks @Leptonator, I get the example that is shown above in xls format. The source of it is a system that I don't have an access or any details of its operation.

Comment: I think @Avi is asking "Under certain conditions of a given row in a spreadsheet, I must insert an additional row (or rows) such that I have a _sequence_ of hours (e.g. 8:00, 9:00, ..., 14:00, 15:00).  How do I do this?"

Comment: If this shall run within one `Excel` sheet range, then it is not possible with formulas alone. A formula returns a calculated value into that cell the formula itself is stored in. A formula can't insert or delete cells or rows. But multiple formulas in a target range can get values from a source range into that target range. Please clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are inserting or deleting rows, it is important to remember that you need to start at the bottom and work towards the top. If you try top-to-bottom, you will inevitably skip rows or loop through rows you have already covered.

```
Sub insertHourly()
    Dim rw As Long, hr As Long, hrs As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For rw = (.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1) To 2 Step -1
            hrs = Round((.Cells(rw + 1, 1).Value2 - .Cells(rw, 1).Value2) * 24, 0)
            For hr = 2 To hrs
                .Cells(rw + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
                .Cells(rw + 1, 1) = .Cells(rw + 2, 1) - TimeSerial(1, 0, 0)
                .Cells(rw + 1, 4) = 1
            Next hr
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: insert_hours]
                  <sup>Before insertHourly procedure</sup>

[image: insert_hours_results]
                  <sup>After insertHourly procedure</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jeeped, does your code include also the final calculation of calculating the missing lines Value?

Comment: As an [enthusiast programmer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), I'm sure you will welcome the oppotunity I've left for you to complete what I've started with a little substraction and division.